# Program keeps running even after the error appeared

Tags: c, arrays, exit, break, eof

I have a program that retrieves some numbers from a file into an array. The last problem that I have is that my program keeps running even though it cannot open the file, instead of ending it. Even when it says program is over, the menu from main appears again but doesn't show any data

```
int main (void)

{ 
int choice, max, min;
float avg;
int test[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS];
int file_opened;
int number_of_students;

file_opened = get_test_scores(test, &number_of_students);

if (file_opened == 0)
{
  do
  {
    choice = menu();
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 0: printf("\nProgram is over.\n");
              break;
    case 1: test_avg(&avg, test, number_of_students);
            printf("\nAverage score on test = %5.2f\n", avg);
            break;
    case 2: test_max_min(number_of_students, &max, &min, test);
            printf("\nMaximum score = %3d\n"
                      "Minimum score = %3d\n", max, min);
            break;
    case 3: print_test(test,number_of_students);
            break;
    default:
            printf("This should never happen!");
  }

  } while (choice != 0);
}

return 0;
 }

int get_test_scores(int test[], int* size)
{
FILE* sp_input;    // Pointer to the input stream (from a file)
  int i;
 sp_input = fopen("a20.dat", "r");                                               

  if (sp_input == NULL)
     printf("\nUnable to open the file a20.dat\n");
  else
  {
    while( fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i])!=EOF)
    {
    i=i+1;
    ++*size;
    }
    fclose(sp_input);    // Close the stream
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: add return 0 if file cannot be read, maybe

Comment: `int i;` --> `int i = 0;` and Need `*size = 0;`

Comment: `get_teset_scores()` always returns 1, whether it opened the file or not... though that should prevent your menu from appearing even when it can open the file, which is kind of the opposite of what you describe...

Comment: `fclose(sp_input);` --> `fclose(sp_input); return 0;`

Comment: Also, check that `fscanf()` returns 1 (the number of fields to scan) instead of checking that it doesn't return `EOF`... otherwise you'll get an infinite loop if there's something in the file it can't interpret as a number.

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Are you expecting us to read your mind as to what header files are being included?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) indent consistently.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code is missing the prototypes for the functions: `print_test()`, `get_test_scores()`, `test_avg()`, `test)max_min()`, `menu()`.  The posted code is missing the `#define` statements for `MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS`.  The posted code has the unused variable `test`.  Please correct the posted code and re-post as an edit (do not erase the current posted code.

Comment: most likely, the function: `menu()` is not clearing `stdin` before getting the 'choice' value so any left over newline is being returned by `menu()` rather than the users' new 'choice` integer or perhaps is returning a '0' character = 0x30 rather than '0x0000000000000000`   <<-- This is one of the main reasons that posted code needs to be complete, short, cleanly compiles, and still shows the problem.

Comment: these two lines are not correct: `if (sp_input == NULL)
        printf("\nUnable to open the file a20.dat\n");`  1) output error message to `stderr`, not `stdout`, 2) when a system function fails, output the reason the OS thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `if ( !sp_input ) { perror( "fopen for reading a20.dat failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are both visible by the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: the function: `get_test_scores()` returns `1`, but that is NOT what the `main()` function is expected when the open of the input file was successful,  per this statement: `if (file_opened == 0)` on success, the function: `get_test_scores()` is expecting a 0, not a 1

Comment: this line: while( fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i])!=EOF) is rather 'iffy' there are other reasons beside EOF that a call to fscanf() can fail. Suggest: while( fscanf(sp_input, "%d", &test[i]) == 1) Also the variable i has not been initialized. Suggest replacing: int i; with int i = 0;  Note: accessing: `&test[i]` when I has not been initialized is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: due to precedence of operators this line: `++*size;` will NOT perform the desired operation.  Suggest: `++(*size);`

Comment: the variable `number_of_students` has not been initialized, so when that variable is being increment in the function: `get_test_scores()` the increment can be done, but the resulting number is unknown.  When that variable is passed to `test_avg()`, etc the value could be anything, which is undefined behavior.  Suggest replacing: `int number_of_students;`  with: `int number_of_students = 0;`

Comment: please post the source for the function: `menu()` as an additional edit, so we can determine if the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it keeps running...

```
if (file_opened == 0)
{
  do
  {
```

means that if the file has *not* been opened, to do the loop. You want:

```
if (file_opened != 0)
```

See also comments about other bugs.